# json_normalize does not read all data

Tags: json, pandas

I have a `json` file that I want to flatten and retrieve all the information into a pandas dataframe. The `json` file looks like this:

```
jsonstr = {
  "calculation": {
    "id": "3k3k3k3kwk3kwk",
    "Id": 23,
    "submissionDate": 1622428064679,
    "serverVersion": "3.3.5.6.r",
    "tag": [
      {
        "code": "qq4059331155113278",
        "manual": {
          "location": {
            "x": 26.5717,
            "y": 59.4313,
            "z": 0.0,
            "floor": 0
          },
          "timestamp": 1599486138000
        },
        "device": null,
        "measurements": [
          {
            "Address": "D_333",
            "subcell": "",
            "frequency": 14.0,
            "dfId": 0
          },
          {
            "trxAddress": "D_334",
            "subcell": "",
            "frequency": 11.0,
            "dfId": 0
          }]
    }]
}
}
```

Now, as usual, I do the following. I thought that this would return all the "fields", including `id`, `Id`, `submissionDate` and so on

```
import os, json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

file = './Testjson.json'
#file = './jsondumps/ff80818178f93bd90179ab51781e1c95.json'
with open(file) as json_string:
    jsonstr = json.load(json_string)

labels = pd.json_normalize(jsonstr, record_path=['calculation','tag'])
```

But in fact, it returns:

```
   code device  \
0  qq4059331155113278   None   

                                        measurements  manual.location.x  \
0  [{'Address': 'D_333', 'subcell': '', 'frequenc...            26.5717   

   manual.location.y  manual.location.z  manual.location.floor  \
0            59.4313                0.0                      0   

   manual.timestamp  
0     1599486138000
```

and trying the following

```
labels = pd.json_normalize(jsonstr, record_path=['calculation','tag'], meta=['id', 'Id'])
```

returns an error:

```
KeyError: 'id'
```

which makes sense. But What am I doing wrong to begin with? Why can I not get all the fields under `calculation` since they are in the path?

Greatful for any insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly off on the meta argument. `id` and `Id` are at the end of the dataframe.

If you are looking to flatten the entire json, look into `flatten_json`. It's a pretty good library to use with nested json.

```
pd.json_normalize(jsonstr, record_path=['calculation','tag'],  meta=[['calculation','id'],['calculation','Id']])

                 code device                                       measurements  manual.location.x  manual.location.y  manual.location.z  manual.location.floor  manual.timestamp  calculation.id calculation.Id
0  qq4059331155113278   null  [{'Address': 'D_333', 'subcell': '', 'frequenc...            26.5717            59.4313                0.0                      0     1599486138000  3k3k3k3kwk3kwk             23
```

Comment: On the ```flatten_json```: I tried this on the entire ```json``` and for some wierd reason it fails with the error ```Cannot allocate 5.18 TB of memory``` (or something similar). While doing it for individual parts of the file works fine. This is why I need the ids so I may merge on them.